# A Script to run a program based on the state of a website

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, remote-access

Platform Windows XP, - 7:

Scripting language, I'm open to suggestions, but was thinking about using Windows Power Shell

Need a script that basically checks the state of a website on the internet. It will be running all the time in the background, checking every 15 minutes or so. If the site is up, then I want it to run openvpn and create a tunnel to a ip address defined in the openvpn config.

If the website is down, terminate the tunnel.

New to scripting, thanks in advance.

If you can recommend any good beginner books on Windows Powershell that would be a plus.

Thanks

Brian

Answer (score 0):

you may check this website for the powershell script which checks the a website availability

http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/monitor-web-site-availability/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/otto/archive/2007/08/23/quick-and-dirty-web-site-monitoring-with-powershell.aspx

http://blogs.iis.net/ma_khan/archive/2010/09/12/how-to-use-microsoft-web-administration-from-powershell.aspx

You may have to tweak a bit according to your needs

MSDN / Technet would a good resource for learning powershell

-Karthik